# How to prevent Grid items to have same height

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, grid, tailwind-css

[Grid forcing to have small div to have same height as neighbor div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrFfM.png). But the problem is, the grid is forcing to have items same height even though i have applied `h-fit`. I want items to come below to each other. In addition, `flex box` also shows same behavior.

```
<div className="grid lg:grid-cols-2 sm:grid-cols-1 gap-4">
{accounts.map((account, index) => (
   <div key={index} className="my-4  bg-stone-300 accountsCard rounded-md hover:shadow-md  h-fit">
   //.....
)}
   </div>
</div>
```

My expectations: I want items to come below to each other.

Comment: You're seeking a masonry effect, which neither Flex nor Grid possess (currently).